# JTextField Not Able to be Referenced

Tags: java, swing, scope, jtextfield

I'm working on a project for employee management with SQL Server and Java. While adding in the functionality for `addEmployee` I ran into this problem.

I cannot reference the `JTextField` components (`txtName`, `txtAge`  and `txtAddress`). I may be completely missing something. While trying to create the `jButtonActionPerformed()` method for the `Add` button, the `getText()` for all text fields is giving an error and none of the text field names are showing up for auto-correction as if they do not exist.

Can someone help me figure out how to use the text field objects within this code?

```
public class EmployeeDialog extends javax.swing.JDialog {

/**
 * Creates new form EmployeeDialog
 */
public EmployeeDialog(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
    super(parent, modal);
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    javax.swing.JTextField txtAddress = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    javax.swing.JTextField txtAge = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    javax.swing.JButton btnCancel = new javax.swing.JButton();
    javax.swing.JButton jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    javax.swing.JTextField txtName = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setText("Name:");

    jLabel2.setText("Age:");

    jLabel3.setText("Address:");

    btnCancel.setText("Cancel");
    btnCancel.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnCancelActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton1.setText("Add");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(46, 46, 46)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(33, 33, 33)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 155, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(btnCancel))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1))
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(txtAge)
                        .addComponent(txtAddress)
                        .addComponent(txtName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 240, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
            .addContainerGap(57, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(32, 32, 32)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(txtName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addComponent(txtAge, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addComponent(txtAddress, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(45, 45, 45)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(btnCancel)
                .addComponent(jButton1))
            .addContainerGap(17, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void btnCancelActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    this.dispose();
}                                         

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String name = txtName.getText();
    int age = Integer.parseInt(txtAge.getText());
    String address = txtAddress.getText();
    Employee e = new Employee (name, age, address);
    EmployeeManager em = (EmployeeManager) this.getParent();
    em.addEmployee(e);
}                                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(EmployeeDialog.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(EmployeeDialog.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(EmployeeDialog.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(EmployeeDialog.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the dialog */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            EmployeeDialog dialog = new EmployeeDialog(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true);
            dialog.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: All the properties you are trying to access are defined as local variables within the `initComponents` method, they won't be accessible outside it

Answer (score 0):

All the fields you are trying to access are defined as local variables to the `initComponents` method.  They won't be accessible outside of its context...

```
private void initComponents() {

    javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    javax.swing.JTextField txtAddress = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    javax.swing.JTextField txtAge = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    javax.swing.JButton btnCancel = new javax.swing.JButton();
    javax.swing.JButton jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    javax.swing.JTextField txtName = new javax.swing.JTextField();
```

Go to Netbeans form designer for your class.  Click one of the fields, select the "Code" tab and uncheck the "Use Local Variable" option

[image: Component Properties Editor]

Repeat and rinse for all the components you want to be able to access from within the whole class